# Is there an overhead with tracking when using EF6.1 and if so how can I remove this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some complex queries like this:

```
  var contents = await db.Contents
            .Where(q => q.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId || contentStatusId == 0)
            .Where(q => q.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId || contentTypeId == 0)
            .Where(q => q.CreatedBy == contentCreatedBy || contentCreatedBy == "0")
            .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == contentModifiedBy || contentModifiedBy == "0")
            .Where(q => q.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .ToListAsync();
```

I send the results back to my web API and I do not need any tracking. Does EF automatically add tracking and if so is that an overhead that I do not need. Also if it does then is there a way I can turn off the tracking ?

Comment: FYI, performance with and without tracking : http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an overhead. You can use [AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on IQueryable or your DbSet.

```
var contents = await db.Contents
        .Where(q => q.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId || contentStatusId == 0)
        .Where(q => q.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId || contentTypeId == 0)
        .Where(q => q.CreatedBy == contentCreatedBy || contentCreatedBy == "0")
        .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == contentModifiedBy || contentModifiedBy == "0")
        .Where(q => q.SubjectId == subjectId)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
```